# jQuery advanced selector - select :selected from parent div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can't get this selector to work...

```
$('div#associations_notes select#company :selected').val()
```

also tried..

```
$('div#associations_notes > select#company :selected').val()
```

and..

```
$('~ select#company :selected','div#associations_notes').val()
```

HTML:

```
<div id="associations_notes">
<div id="associated_companies_box"> 
<div id="company_associations_list"></div>
<div id="association_company" style="display:none;">
<select name="association_id" id=company class=works_for>
<option value="35">Compaq</option>
```

...

any thoughts?

Comment: what is your html and what are you trying to get..

Comment: I am asumming that you are trying to namespace elements in html using ids and classes. if you want to walk through the dom elements for selecting a child element, you can also use **parent()**, **children()** and **find()** methods available with jquery. also try removing the space before `:selected`

Comment: You don't have quotes for the select element's id and class. Maybe that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one selected option, you should test the value of the `select` element, rather than finding the `selected` options. This will be computationally quicker (and quicker to code as well).

```
$('#company').val();
```

The selector can be reduced to the `id` selector because `id` properties must be unique to the page, so you almost certainly don't need to test its ancestors.

Comment: If you have multiple elements with the same ID on a page, don't expect anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to get the value of the `option` that was selected

```
$('#company option:selected').val();

  <select id="mySelect">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
    <option>option 5</option>
    <option>option 6</option>
  </select>
```

It's the `<option>` that you need, not the `<select>` value

Comment: i tried $('div#associations_notes select#company option:selected').val() but that still does not work...hmmm

Comment: just use `$('#company option:selected').val();` and nothing more. With Firebug or inspector on Chrome/Safari you can run your selectors